# How can I make a python list of strings to be read as arguments of a python function? [remake]

Tags: python, list

As my original question was closed due to 'not being minimalistic', I will explain what I want to do by giving you an example that I have made up.

I have a function called 'persona()' and this function has argument called **'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'** that just gets *bool* as its value (true or false) like this:

```
face = persona(alpha=true, beta=false, gamma=false)
```

and I have a list that looks like below because I had no other option to get it otherwise.

```
ar_list = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']
ar_column = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

If I want to get element in **ar_list** as an argument name of function **persona()**, how can I achieve this? Below was what I 'hoped' to do, but this surely will not work. But I hope there are ways to achieve something like this.

```
for ar in ar_column:
    pesona(ar_list[0] = (some calculation using 'alpha' and ar),
           ar_list[1] = (some calculation using 'beta' and ar),
           ar_list[2] = (some calculation using 'gamma' and ar))
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `persona(*ar_list)` ?

Comment: you can directly pass list to function `persona(ar_list)` or if you want to pass it as separate variable than pass it as *argv that is `persona(*argv)`

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. You say the arguments to your function are bools, but then you say you want to pass a list of strings as arguments to the function. A little more code with your intended result would be helpful here.

Comment: @HenriChab I don't think that's what he's after. As far as I understand his question, he wants the strings in the list to be the names of variables of type boolean.

Comment: Your request is unclear.  You claim that you have an argument with a name that is a tuple of three strings; this is not legal Python.  Then you imply that you want to pass a list of those strings to your function; this is covered in any tutorial on functions, so I expect that you want something else.  You also say that you want the function argument to "get" a Boolean value -- which would be a trivial lesson from the same tutorial.

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang Yop, you're right, even though I tried to understand very hard, still not sure what he really wants to do.

Comment: @HenriChab Edited my question for everyone else didn't understand

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang How about now?

Comment: If you want the alpha argument to get the string "alpha" and the beta argument to get the string "beta" and the gamma argument to get the string "gamma", then @HenriChab's original comment was exactly right,  `persona(*ar_list)`.

Comment: @Prune If what I wanted to know was in something that you said, I didn't just posted my question here. Wonder if you got it after I edited my question now.

Comment: @Haidus There is probably a better way to do it, than to create dynamic variables. But if it's really necessary, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164).

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang Thanks, but definitely not meant that. I added some context hoping for others to better understand my question

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you are looking for this :

[Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

Here `*a,`  can have more than one variables and passing it to function.
Than unpacking it in function.

```
*a, = True, False, True

def persona (*a):
    alpha, beta, gamma = a
    print(alpha, beta, gamma)

persona(*a)
```

Comment: added some context to my question to get myself understood.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ar in ar_column:
    ar_dict = {i:(some calculation using 'alpha' and ar) for i in ar_list}
    persona(**ar_dict)
```

Comment: So, functions use dictionary as ways of saving their arguments?